# Post video to Facebook using Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good day,
I wanted to receive app review, but I can’t do it, my app is rejected because the screencast does not meet the requirements. As far as I understand the screen where user confirms the video upload should be shown for the app review. 
I want the user to be able to upload videos to our application without Facebook client installed on the user’s device. When I use ShareDialog with ShareVideoContent, the shareDialog.canShow(content) returns “false” if the user doesn’t have facebook client on a device. I use GraphRequest, POST on the "me/videos", but the response is «No permission to publish the video».
Could you tell me what code should be used for the screen to be appeared?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post a video using the graph API, you must

1. Login the user in your app
2. Request the permission to your app
3. Upload the video.

Have you done all theses steps ?